# Unable to find database

Tags: php, sql, database

I created a php file, and it is on my server. After I open the php file from chrome, it is showing "Unable to find database".

```
<?php

    $dbhost = "fdb7.biz.nf";
    $database = "2065616_knurum";
    $username = "2065616_knurum";
    $dbpass = "XXXXXXXXX";

    mysqli_connect($dbhost, $username, $dbpass, $database);

    @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to find database");

    $name = isset($_GET["name"]) ? $_GET["name"] : '';

    $message = isset($_GET["message"]) ? $_GET["message"] : '';


    $query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('', '$name', '$message')";

    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));

    mysql_close();

    echo"hello";
    ?>
```

After several helpers comments, here is right solution, and it worked.thank you for all replied helpers.

```
$dbhost = "fdb7.biz.nf";
$database = "2065616_knurum";
$username = "2065616_knurum";
$dbpass = "XXXXXXXX";

$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $username, $dbpass, $database);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}


$name = isset($_GET["name"]) ? $_GET["name"] : '';

$message = isset($_GET["message"]) ? $_GET["message"] : '';

$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('', '$name', '$message')";

mysqli_query($link, $query) or die (mysqli_error("error"));


echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: did you check your pockets??? back of the sofa??? under the car seat???? it may be where your code is hiding because I can't find that either?  as well as the evidence that you have tried to fix the issue.... all missing!!!

Comment: @gavgrif thank you for you commit. now the code is not hidden.

Comment: Hi, may you check the green check to my answer if it's help

Answer (score 3):

```
1) check your database spelling.
2) have you given all the required privileges to user?
3) username and password is correct ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this reference from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

```
<?php

$dbhost = "fdb7.biz.nf";
$database = "2065616_knurum";
$username = "2065616_knurum";
$dbpass = "XXXXXXXXX";

$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $username, $dbpass, $database);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the use of the libraries `mysql` and `mysqli`.

Chose the latter an stick with it

i.e.

```
 @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to find database");
```

should be

```
 @mysqli_select_db($database) or die("Unable to find database");
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you cannot mix `mysql_*` functions and `mysqli_*` functions, the latter is better as `mysql_*` has already been deprecated.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $username, $dbpass, $database);

$query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('', '$name', '$message')";

mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error("error"));

mysqli_close();
```

---

Also, you shouldn't suppress error messages:

```
@mysqli_select_db($database) or die("Unable to find database");
```

Remove `@` to enable error reporting. It's very useful in diagnosing syntax errors.